# TSQL - If Valid is true for at least 1 user in each group then return that group as Valid?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, row

Essentially I want to run a query that returns a list of all the DISTINCT Groups, and if Valid is true for at least 1 user in each group then return that group as true. Otherwise return that group as false. Many thanks

This is my table:

```
UserID | GroupID | Valid
------------------------
1         1        True
2         2        False
3         3        False
4         1        False
5         4        True
```

Results expected

```
UserID | GroupID | Valid
------------------------
1         1        True
2         2        False
3         3        False
5         4        True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by groupid
                                order by (case when valid = 'True' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, answer chosen

Answer (score 1):

You can do this `count` and `min` window functions. (assuming your SQL Server version supports them)

```
select first_user as userid,groupid,new_valid as valid
from (
select t.*
,min(userID) over(partition by groupid) as first_user
,case when count(case when valid='True' then 1 end) over(partition by groupid) > 0 then 'True' else 'False' end as new_valid
from tbl t
) t
where first_user=userID
```

If you need the *first* true or false userID per groupID, use

```
select first_user as userid,groupid,new_valid as valid
from (
select t.*
,case when count(case when valid='True' then 1 end) over(partition by groupid) > 0 then min(case when valid='True' then userID end) over(partition by groupid)
 else min(userID) over(partition by groupid) end as first_user
,case when count(case when valid='True' then 1 end) over(partition by groupid) > 0 then 'True' else 'False' end as new_valid
from tbl t
) t
where first_user=userID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You Can do Something like this:

```
SELECT      MAX(UserID),
            GroupID,
            Valid 
FROM        yourtable
WHERE       Valid = 1 
OR          (Valid = 0 and GroupID not in (SELECT GroupID FROM yourtable WHERE Valid = 1))
Group By    GroupID, Valid
order by    MAX(UserID)
```

This way you will get the last UserID for one group. If want the first, just change MAX to MIN.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)